# Enable/Disable <asp:Panel> and all its control using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have `asp:panel` on my page. At run time, I add controls to this panel, and I want to disable/enable all its controls as per business logic.

I tried with this:

```
document.getElementById('mypanel').disabled = true;
```

But it is not working.

Does anyone has any idea to make this work?

Comment: Do/Can you use the jQuery framework?

Comment: Note that if you disable form elements, their value won't be sent to the server when posting back the data. If you want the value to be sent, assign their `readOnly` property instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An `asp:Panel` just produces a div element. This isn't a form control, it's just there for structure.

To disable every input control inside of it, if you are using jQuery, try:

```
$("#<%=mypanel.ClientID%> input").attr("disabled", true);
```

Or plain ol' JavaScript:

```
var controls = document.getElementById("<%=mypanel.ClientID%>").getElementsByTagName("input");

for (var i = 0; i < controls.length; i++)
    controls[i].disabled = true;
```

Comment: Correct approach, but ASP.NET will produce "dynamic" ID so to get it use such code: `document.getElementById("<%=mypanel.ClientID%>")`

Answer (score 0):

try the following code snippet

```
<div>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnl" runat="server">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" />
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" />
            <asp:CheckBox Text="text" runat="server" />
        </asp:Panel>
        <input type="button" name="name" value=" Test" onclick="ED();" />
    </div>


 <script type="text/javascript">
    function ED() {
        var div_to_disable = document.getElementById('<%=pnl.ClientID %>').getElementsByTagName("input");
        var children = div_to_disable;//.childNodes;
        for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                children[i].disabled = true;
        };
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Not good, it won't iterate deep enough - what if the Panel contains another Panel that contains textbox? `getElementsByTagName` is ideal for such things..

Comment: no problem, however I must comment also that ZDYN answer is exactly the same except for the ID which you get properly..

Answer (score 0):

**It is Work 100% **

```js
 function EnableDisableRadio(CheckBox1) {
            var controls = document.getElementById("<%=Panel1.ClientID%>").getElementsByTagName("input");
            for (var i = 0; i < controls.length; i++)
                controls[i].disabled = CheckBox1.checked ? false : true;
        }
```

```html
 <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="check" onclick="EnableDisableRadio(this)"/>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Width="160px" Enabled="False">
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </asp:Panel>
    
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="check" onclick="EnableDisableRadio(this)"/>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Width="160px" Enabled="False">
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </asp:Panel>
    
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

```html
 <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="check" onclick="EnableDisableRadio(this)"/>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Width="160px" Enabled="False">
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </asp:Panel>
    
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score -3):

asp:panel is a server control. Why are you manipulating it at client side!? Just use `mypanel.enable = false` in code behind